# Partitioned memory stick only works on Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, gparted

Please note: I've been looking through the "Questions that may already have your answer" but none of help.

I attempted to partition a memory stick to make a separate drive for PortableApps, but it seems the second partition on the memory stick only appears on my Ubuntu system. And on Windows only my 1st partition appears.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing wrong with the way Ubuntu has partitioned the USB Stick, it is a limitation of Windows only being able to see the first partition on the USB stick !

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-hardware/why-does-windows-not-support-multiple-partitions/8a217e1b-b3e8-4c47-9a3c-2f0660622ba7

> Typically, you cannot create partitions on removable disks (in other
>   words, USB drives).
>
> You won't be able to perform the same using Windows operating system.
>
> However, certain third party software can flip the removable bit on a
>   USB drive so that the Windows operating system reads it as a fixed
>   drive.
>
> Note: Using Third Party Software, including hardware drivers can cause
>   serious problems that may prevent your computer from booting properly.
>   Microsoft cannot guarantee that any problems resulting from the use of
>   Third Party Software can be solved. Using Third Party Software is at
>   your own risk.

Comment: Is it possible to fix this issue?

Comment: Oh ok. I'll see to that.

Comment: See my updated answer, it is not something I have tried, but it appears there are tools you can use.

Comment: I'm looking up software on the internet right now.

Comment: Ah, nvm. I'm gonna revert back to how it was before, I can't seem to find much tools.